# Eclipse ADT stuck on splash screen, and high usage on available RAM

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, splash-screen

[image]

My configuration: Linux Mint 13, java-6-openjdk-i386, adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030

I tried to change java to 1.7 using "update-alternatives --config java" but does not has any effect.
As you can see, debugging boot only shows ".options not found", but I can't solve this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cHao the column you are reading is not "Available Ram". This column is "USED Ram".
I have 1,8Gb of free RAM.

Comment: You said it was taking up all available RAM.  That means, literally, that used == available.

Comment: ok. Edited to "high usage". sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have compulsory installed JDK first after you can install ADT ....

Answer (score 0):

Mine happened because my workspace folder path was invalid. I realized that after reinstalling ADT package and selecting a correct workspace path.